# Capitalize or change case of an NSString in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uppercase

I was wondering how to capitalize a string found in an object in an `NSMutableArray`.

An `NSArray` contains the string `'April'` at index 2.
I want this to be changed to `'APRIL'`.

Is there something simple like this?

```
viewNoteDateMonth.text  = [[displayDate objectAtIndex:2] capitalized];
```

Answer (score 395, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
viewNoteDateMonth.text  = [[displayDate objectAtIndex:2] uppercaseString];
```

Btw:
`"april"` is `lowercase` ➔ [[NSString lowercaseString]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lowercaseString)
`"APRIL"` is `UPPERCASE` ➔ [[NSString uppercaseString]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/uppercaseString)
`"April May"` is `Capitalized/Word Caps` ➔ [[NSString capitalizedString]](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/capitalizedString)
`"April may"` is `Sentence caps` ➔ *(method missing; see workaround below)*

Hence what you want is called "**uppercase**", not "**capitalized**". ;)

As for "Sentence Caps" one has to keep in mind that usually "Sentence" means "entire string". If you wish for real sentences use the second method, below, otherwise the first:

```
@interface NSString ()

- (NSString *)sentenceCapitalizedString; // sentence == entire string
- (NSString *)realSentenceCapitalizedString; // sentence == real sentences

@end

@implementation NSString

- (NSString *)sentenceCapitalizedString {
    if (![self length]) {
        return [NSString string];
    }
    NSString *uppercase = [[self substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
    NSString *lowercase = [[self substringFromIndex:1] lowercaseString];
    return [uppercase stringByAppendingString:lowercase];
}

- (NSString *)realSentenceCapitalizedString {
    __block NSMutableString *mutableSelf = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self];
    [self enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])
                             options:NSStringEnumerationBySentences
                          usingBlock:^(NSString *sentence, NSRange sentenceRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        [mutableSelf replaceCharactersInRange:sentenceRange withString:[sentence sentenceCapitalizedString]];
    }];
    return [NSString stringWithString:mutableSelf]; // or just return mutableSelf.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 20):

```
viewNoteDateMonth.text  = [[displayDate objectAtIndex:2] uppercaseString];
```

Documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/uppercaseString

You can also use [lowercaseString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lowercaseString) and [capitalizedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/capitalizedString)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needed the above in swift :

SWIFT 3.0 and above :

this will capitalize your string, make the first letter capital :

```
viewNoteDateMonth.text  = yourString.capitalized
```

this will uppercase your string, make all the string upper case :

```
viewNoteDateMonth.text  = yourString.uppercased()
```